# ESbuild fails when bundling GSAP

Tags: javascript, gsap, pnpm, esbuild

I have a project where I am using esbuild to bundle some modules that use GSAP. When I initialize a basic timeline and then build the project the build files return what appears to be an error saying that

> GSAP hasn't been initialized

The bundled file output is to large to put on here so ive included a screen shot of the entire file as well [Bundle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awuD8.png). Ive listed as much as I can here:

```
"use strict";(()=>{function pt(f){if(f===void 0)throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called");return f}function Ri(f,t){f.prototype=Object.create(t.prototype),f.prototype.constructor=f,f.__proto__=t}var it={autoSleep:120,force3D:"auto",nullTargetWarn:1,units:{lineHeight:""}}...
```

The pre-bundled files look like this:

```
import { gsap } from 'gsap';

const name = 'Hello World';
const tl = gsap.timeline();
```

And Build file here:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import * as esbuild from 'esbuild';
import { readdirSync } from 'fs';
import { join, sep } from 'path';

// Config output
const BUILD_DIRECTORY = 'dist';
const PRODUCTION = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

// Config entrypoint files
const ENTRY_POINTS = ['src/index.ts'];

// Config dev serving
const LIVE_RELOAD = !PRODUCTION;
const SERVE_PORT = 3000;

// Create context
const context = await esbuild.context({
  bundle: true,
  entryPoints: ENTRY_POINTS,
  outdir: BUILD_DIRECTORY,
  minify: PRODUCTION,
  sourcemap: !PRODUCTION,
  target: PRODUCTION ? 'es2019' : 'esnext',
  inject: LIVE_RELOAD ? ['./bin/live-reload.js'] : undefined,
  define: {
    SERVE_PORT: `${SERVE_PORT}`,
  },
});

// Build files in prod
if (PRODUCTION) {
  await context.rebuild();
  context.dispose();
}

// Watch and serve files in dev
else {
  await context.watch();
  await context
    .serve({
      servedir: BUILD_DIRECTORY,
      port: SERVE_PORT,
    })
    .then(({ port }) => {
      logServedFiles(BUILD_DIRECTORY, port);
    });
}

/**
 * Logs information about the files that are being served during local development.
 * @param {string} servedir
 * @param {number} port
 */
function logServedFiles(servedir, port) {
  /**
   * Recursively gets all files in a directory.
   * @param {string} dirPath
   * @returns {string[]} An array of file paths.
   */
  const getFiles = (dirPath) => {
    const files = readdirSync(dirPath, { withFileTypes: true }).map((dirent) => {
      const path = join(dirPath, dirent.name);
      return dirent.isDirectory() ? getFiles(path) : path;
    });

    return files.flat();
  };

  const files = getFiles(servedir);

  const filesInfo = files
    .map((file) => {
      if (file.endsWith('.map')) return;

      // Normalize path and create file location
      const paths = file.split(sep);
      paths[0] = `http://localhost:${port}`;

      const location = paths.join('/');

      // Create import suggestion
      const tag = location.endsWith('.css')
        ? `<link href="${location}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`
        : `<script defer src="${location}"></script>`;

      return {
        'File Location': location,
        'Import Suggestion': tag,
      };
    })
    .filter(Boolean);

  console.table(filesInfo);
}
```

When the definition of the timeline is commented out and re-built the error no longer appears.

Expected behavior: When built, the resulting files do not contain a RefrenceError.

Does anyone have any insights here?

Comment: [Don't show images of text](/help/how-to-ask) (or links to images of text), just show the text. But in this case, the minified result tells us nothing, so no reason to include it.What you _should_ include, however, is the literal error you're looking at. That way folks can hopefully recognize it as something they've run across before. Although on a modern JS note: don't use `window`. Use `globalThis`. But even better of course would be to not "pollute" the global namespace, you should `export` that `Webflow` so that anything else that needs it can in turn import it.